# What's a good way to circumvent the mobile web's broken video implementation?

Tags: javascript, mobile, video, mp4, webm

I'm wondering if there are any solutions to circumventing the problems with mobile browsers hi-jacking native video implementations on the web. Specifically, I'm looking to be able to **autoplay** and **loop** video.

I've already looked at multiple **JavaScript video decoders** which, essentially, decode the video, on the fly, and push the frames to a `canvas` element. These solutions, unfortunately, aren't performant on **mobile** (but do work on desktop quite well).

Animated **GIFs** are not viable solutions as the image quality is poor and I'd like to maintain a relatively **small file size**. I'm exporting the videos to `webm` and would like to use that (or another video format), if possible, but am  open to a JavaScript `APNG` or animated `WEBP` decoder, if one is out there.

Again, the solution needs to be performant on mobile web browsers and have the ability to autoplay and loop. Appreciate any ideas, thoughts, libraries or resources you may know of.

Cheers!

Comment: I've done some research on the same topic, but you're pretty much out of luck. The "big two" mobile operating systems do not support inline video, unless you consider using Flash on Android.

Comment: I'm not really looking for inline video so much as an alternative to video for mobile.